# Save scroll position while doing php get request in same page

Tags: javascript, php, get-request

I have list of company workers. When I click to a worker, in corner of page showing workers image from mysql database. and mysql SELECT parameters I get from url:

Example:

```
<a href="<?php echo '?imgid=' . $imgID ?>">John SMITH</a>
```

How can I save my current scroll position when I'm clicking to .

Comment: You need to clarify this step-by-step, when taking what action, the scroll position of what exactly should be remembered?

Comment: For your question, you can use local storage also: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: For your second question, here is a way to do it: https://pastebin.com/raw/BLBSUh7M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<body onload="restoreScrollPos()">  

  <a onclick="setScroll()" href="<?php echo '?imgid=' . $imgID ?>">John SMITH</a> 

</body>

<script> 
function setScroll() {
    let scroll = window.scrollY;
    let scrollString = scroll.toString();
    localStorage.setItem("scrollPosition", scrollString);
}


function restoreScrollPos() {
    let posYString = localStorage.getItem("scrollPosition");
    let posY = parseInt(posYString);
    window.scroll(0, posY);
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
var scroll_position = window.scrollY;
```

and to scroll there:

```
window.scrollTo(0, scroll_position);
```

You can test these out with this code in a new HTML file:

```
<div style="height: 400px;"></div>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" />
<div style="height: 2000px;"></div>
<script>
document.querySelector("#submit").onclick = function () {
    var scroll_position = window.scrollY;
    alert(scroll_position);
    window.scrollTo(0, 100);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I need to use this in a tag onclick, and then page raloading with get parameters in url, after reloading page is not keeping scroll position.
I think that I need to keep scroll_position = window.scrollY; in cookie or in session, can You help me doing that way?